# Failed to connect to MySql from Shiny-docker app

Tags: docker, shiny, dockerfile, shiny-server

I have a `Shiny app` which is hosted in `Ubuntu`. This app depends on data that are updated each day and the updated data is stored in local `MySql server`. To fetch data when App

```
Statistics_FN = function() {
                    library(RMySQL)
                        mydb1 = RMySQL::dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'Application', password = 'XXX*', dbname = 'YYY', 
                                                    host = 'localhost', unix.socket = '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock')
                        Statistics = RMySQL::fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb1, paste("select * from Weekly_Statistics")))

                    dbClearResult(dbListResults(mydb1)[[1]])
                    RMySQL::dbDisconnect(mydb1)
                    detach("package:RMySQL", unload = TRUE)

                    return(Statistics)
                }
                Statistics = Statistics_FN()
```

Now I have dockerized this App with below Docker file -

```
FROM r-base:3.5.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libudunits2-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libv8-dev \
    libgdal-dev \
    libssl-dev

RUN wget --no-verbose https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/VERSION -O "version.txt" && \
    VERSION=$(cat version.txt)  && \
    wget --no-verbose "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-$VERSION-amd64.deb" -O ss-latest.deb && \
    gdebi -n ss-latest.deb && \
    rm -f version.txt ss-latest.deb

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'shinydashboard'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('purrr', 'RMySQL'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', dependencies = TRUE)"

COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /Vol_Lab /srv/shiny-server/

COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]

RUN mkdir /root/app
COPY App /root/app

COPY Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/

EXPOSE 8383

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/app')"]
```

However with above configuration, I failed to run my Dockerized app. When I checked the `docker logs 3655f065c1ed`, I see below line of error

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) :
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I also tried with host = '127.0.0.1', but could not succeed.

Can somebody points me to the right direction how can I connect to local MySql db from my Shiny app contained within Docker?

**Modified `server.R` and `Docker` files based on Duy Phan's reply :-**

```
Statistics_FN = function() {
                    library(RMySQL)
                        mydb1 = RMySQL::dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'Application', password = 'XXX*', dbname = 'YYY', 
                                                    host = 'localhost', port = 3306)
                        Statistics = RMySQL::fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb1, paste("select * from Weekly_Statistics")))

                    dbClearResult(dbListResults(mydb1)[[1]])
                    RMySQL::dbDisconnect(mydb1)
                    detach("package:RMySQL", unload = TRUE)

                    return(Statistics)
                }
                Statistics = Statistics_FN()
```

**Docker file -**

```
FROM r-base:3.5.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libudunits2-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libv8-dev \
    libgdal-dev \
    libssl-dev

RUN wget --no-verbose https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/VERSION -O "version.txt" && \
    VERSION=$(cat version.txt)  && \
    wget --no-verbose "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-$VERSION-amd64.deb" -O ss-latest.deb && \
    gdebi -n ss-latest.deb && \
    rm -f version.txt ss-latest.deb

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'shinydashboard'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('dplyr', 'tidyr', 'RMySQL'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', dependencies = TRUE)"

COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /FinDerivs /srv/shiny-server/

COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]

RUN mkdir /root/app
COPY App /root/app

COPY Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/

EXPOSE 7373
EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/app')"]
```

I am still getting same error :

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) :
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

**Information from **docker ps****

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
0266e80a5464        5fe2ba858107        "R -e shiny::runApp(…"   About an hour ago   Up 28 minutes       3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7373->7373/tcp   ecstatic_hypatia
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind connectting to local MySQL database through TCP instead of unix socket, in the App, replace `unix.socket = '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'` with `port = '3306'`.

Then in Dockerfile, expose also default MySQL port by `EXPOSE 3306`.

Comment: @Bogaso Did you rebuild the image and recreate the container after modifying? Run the container, then in your terminal run `docker ps`, if you see `3306/tcp` in the PORTS column, means the container was created with modified image.

More important point is to make sure MySQL database is running. You can check it by (1) attach to the container's terminal, [use system tool or MySQL CLI](https://serverfault.com/questions/558731/how-to-check-if-mysql-server-is-working-or-not) to check or (2) map the port 3306 to your local machine and use MySQL client to connect to MySQL database.

Comment: I see 3306/tcp (edited my original post with full information on this.) Also I see 'Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-06-25 13:10:59 UTC; 31min ago' with sudo service mysql status - so looks like answers are affirmative to both of your queries

Comment: @Bogaso if you're sure that (1) The app is connecting to database via TCP port instead of unix socket (since I see you had the same error when you connect both ways, but you rebuilt the image already; verify by check the script inside the container); (2) Database is running and accepting traffic on port 3306 (it seems running, you can verify more by mapping container port to host machine and use MySQL client to connect) then I have no idea why it doesn't work.